# Как правильно конвертировать один тип данных в другой

Tags: c#, типы-данных, конвертация

Всем привет, только недавно начал изучать `C#`. И мне не дает покоя конвертация типа данных, сейчас покажу свой пример, и что я хочу сделать. Подскажите, у меня не выходит. Я не могу идти далее, так как не дает покоя данная тема.

```
string age = "15"; // Вот я объявляю строковую переменную, и вкладываю в неё 15. 
int klick = 10; // Также объявил переменную и вложил в неё число 10.
klick = Convert.ToInt32(age); // Тут я не знаю, как эти 15 с переменной age конвертировать в int, что бы потом прибавить 15 + 10. Я ожидаю получить 25.
int i = age + klick; // Ну здесь я пытаюсь произвести сложения переменной строкового типа данных и int, надеясь на то, что строковый переобразовался в int.
Console.WriteLine(i); - Ну здесь собственно вывожу на экран это "чудо".
```

Ребят, повторюсь ещё раз, я учу с самого нуля, и на основе полученных знаний, я постарался сделать свой пример, и почему-то он не работает, помогите, буду благодарен, всем добра.

Comment: int i = age + klick; ошибка здесь - у Вас age имеет тип string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас определены две переменные: `string age` и `int klick`.

Изначально они инициализированы как `"15"` и `10` соответственно, а далее вы пишите такую строчку:

```
klick = Convert.ToInt32(age);
```

этим вы присваиваете переменной `int klick`, конвертированную из строки `"15"`, число `15`. Тем самым вы затираете число `10`. Чтобы получить `25` вам нужно писать так:

```
string age = "15";
int klick = 10;
klick = klick + Convert.ToInt32(age); // или klick += Convert.ToInt32(age);
```

Или сохранить результат конвертации в переменную `i` и потом сложить её вместе с `int klick` например вот так:

```
string age = "15";
int klick = 10;
int i = Convert.ToInt32(age); //Сохраним результат конвертации
klick = klick + i; // или klick += i;
```

Вы попытались переменной `i` присвоить примерно такое: `int = string + int`. Что не позволительно. Для того чтобы привести тип `string` к типу `int` как раз и используют функцию `Convert.ToInt32`. Она принимает в себя `string` (одна из перегрузок этой функции), а возвращает `int`.

Comment: аааа, я понял, спасибо большое. извините за потраченное время )

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вы хотели сделать что то вроде такого?

```
string age = "15";
int klick = 10;

// оператор присваивания, заменен на оператор сложения с присваиванием.
klick += Convert.ToInt32(age);

Console.WriteLine("{0:D}", klick);
```

https://ideone.com/WuMUzU

Comment: Для меня тут не понятна вот эта часть "{0:D}", klick, ну а так я получил ответ на свой вопрос, спасибо Вам )